# Dense subsets of $C^0(B_1,\mathbb C)$.

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces

Let $B_1 := \{z \in \mathbb C : |z| \le 1\},$ and let $C^0(B_1,\mathbb C)$ be the space of continuous complex-valued functions on $B_1$ equipped with the uniform convergence topology. 
Listed below are four subsets of C0(B1,C). For each of them, decide whether or not it is dense in $C^0(B_1,\mathbb C)$.

(a) Restrictions to $B_1$ of polynomials in $z$.

(b) Restrictions to $B_1$ of polynomials in $z$ and $\bar{z}$.

(c) The set of smooth functions $f: B_1 \to \mathbb C$ that vanish on the boundary $\partial B_1$.

(d) The set of smooth functions $f: B_1 \to \mathbb C$ whose normal derivative vanishes along the boundary $\partial B_1$.

I can understand that The convergence we are dealing with is the uniform convergence of functions. Also, I know that in the real case the polynomials are dense in the space of continuous functions. I  am trying to find an analogous result for the complex case. I have a feeling that this may not true in the complex case. If so how to proceed (a) and (b)?

(c) and (d) I don't have much idea. Please share some thoughts. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer:

a) Uniform limits of polynomials are analytic in the open disk. Hence a non-analytic continuous function like $\overline {z}$ cannot be approximated uniformly by polynomials.

b) By Stone Weierstrass Theorem polynomials in $z$ and $\overline {z}$ are dense in the space of continuous functions on $B_1$

c) Limits of function vanishing on the boundary also vanish on the boundary os this class is not dense.

[I do not know the answer to d)].